# Login to sharepoint using Sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, login

When I try connecting to SharePoint site from SharePoint Designer,the log in windows pops up again and again and as a result I am unable to connect to my site.
The user that I am using to login is site administrator and  member of administrators group.

Comment: Is your SharePoint Designer installed locally on the SP server?

Comment: 1. Are you using windows authentication?

2. What happens when you try to open same site in browser, are you prompted for user login?

Comment: yes.use windows authentication.no .i can connect to site.I can use the central administrator too.

Comment: the share point designer dont need an configuration in site or other place or prerequisite?

Comment: anybody have Idea?!!

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands and then try logging in the site:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
```

Comment: thanx! but still has error

Comment: Please post the error that you are facing.

Comment: not show any error.show only login page again.